# trying to add dynamic values from text input to database in codeigniter. but single record values are not getting saved in the same row

Tags: php, codeigniter

**My controller method**

```
public function storePost(){
  foreach ($this->input->post('addmore') as $key=> $value) {
    $this->db->insert('filedata',$value);
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbKqt.png)

Comment: version of CodeIgniter plz

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a `foreach` loop to do the insert. If the input fields have the *exact same names* as the database fields, and if you only want to insert one row at a time, this should work:

```
public function storePost(){
  $this->db->insert('filedata', $this->input->post());
}
```

If you want more control over the post parameters and specify them you could do:

```
public function storePost(){
  $data = array('Image'=>$this->input->post('Image'),
                'Title'=>$this->input->post('Title'),
                'Description'=>$this->input->post('Description'),
                'Qty'=>$this->input->post('Qty'),
                'Price'=>$this->input->post('Price'),
                'Date'=>$this->input->post('Date')
                );
  $this->db->insert('filedata', $data);
}
```

If you are using Codeigniter 4 then use the Request Class and `$request->getVar('fieldname')` instead of `$this->input->post('fieldname')`

See the docs:
Codeigniter 4 Request Class: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/incomingrequest.html?highlight=post#getVar

Codeigniter 3 Input Class:
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/input.html#using-post-get-cookie-or-server-data